# Variable can't be used in useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, scope, react-hooks

Why do I get this error:

> *'height' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)*

```
useEffect(() => {
   let height = contentDiv.current ? contentDiv.current.scrollHeight : 0;
   let test = (height: number) => height;
   setExpandedHeight(test);
  }, [children]
);
```

Am I missing something? Why is it not possible to use variable in function inside the useEffect?

Comment: Well as is written in error. You never used `height` which you have declared.

Comment: The local variable in the useEffect callback is shadowed inside the test function by its parameter - is that what you indended?

Answer (score 0):

this is an arrow function

```
let test = (height: number) => height;
```

it takes a parameter and returns it, it doesn't use your variable, you could do something like

```
useEffect(() => {
  let height = contentDiv.current ? contentDiv.current.scrollHeight : 0;
  let test = (height: number) => height;
  setExpandedHeight(test(height));
}, [children]);
```

but it wouldn't be really useful